# Spring keep reading all profile configuration whe executing with specific profile

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have this configuration:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: test
  profiles:
    active: '@profileActive@'

server:
  port: 8081

#dev config
---
spring:
  config:
    active:
      on-profile: dev
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    show-sql: true
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db
    username: root
    password: root
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

#prod config
---
spring:
  config:
    active:
      on-profile: prod
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    show-sql: true
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/db
    username: root
    password: root
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

when I run spring with the dev profile like this:

```
./mvnw -Pdev spring-boot:run
```

it also reads the prod configuration and tries to execute it, which is in this case the mysql configuration but throws an error saying it couldn't connect to host "`mysql`" (since it's an unknown host)
this is weird because that was intended for prod and for dev spring should only read dev config
I'm using it with maven profile and this is my pom config:

```
<resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.yaml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <build.profile.id>dev</build.profile.id>
                <profileActivate>dev</profileActivate>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <build.profile.id>prod</build.profile.id>
                <profileActivate>prod</profileActivate>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

Comment: Why have you defined maven profiles for a spring boot application? You can activate a spring profile via command line..

Answer (score 0):

#### Short answer

You made a typo on `active` - it should be `activate`. Reference: [Config File Processing in Spring Boot](https://spring.io/blog/2020/08/14/config-file-processing-in-spring-boot-2-4/#profile-specific-documents).

#### Longer Explanation

Please use the following definition for each profile you defined after your `---` separator:

```yaml
spring:
    config:
        activate:
            on-profile: <profilename>
```

An actual example based on your input:

```yaml
#dev config
---
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: dev
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    show-sql: true
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db
    username: root
    password: root
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

Finally, a suggestion: if you use a lot of profiles, personally I would like to recommend to distribute each profile to a separate YAML file with the following pattern `application-<profilename>.yaml`. For example:

- `application-dev.yaml`
- `application-prod.yaml`
- `application-test.yaml`